# android chunk translation file location

Tags: android

For [Chunk Tranlation](http://www.x5software.com/chunk/examples/ChunkExample?example=localize&loc=en_US), where should I place translate.csv in android?
thank you

```
    Theme theme = new Theme(loader);
    theme.setLocale("en_US);
```

Comment: Why not use standard android localization?